# Render a part of page in React router dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a ReactJS application with basic routing like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Global from './global'
import Authentication from './authentication'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Global />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Authentication />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

Inside the Global component I have this code

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import MainContent from "./MainContent";

const Global = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Header />
      <MainContent />
    </>
  );
};

export default Global;
```

I want to embed some routing inside the MainContent component like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Sales from '../../pages/Sales'
import Products from '../../pages/Products'

const MainContent = () => {
  return (
    <div className='content-body'>
      <Routes>
         <Route path="/sales" element={<Sales />} />
         <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainContent
```

I am using `react-router-dom@6` but this routing is not working properly. The embedded route may be causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to embed in another way and if you want to add your `Sidebar` and `Header`, you'll need to add a `Layout` with an `Outlet`
Check for more here : https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

Here's what you can do :

in you `App`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
         <Route path="/sales" element={<Sales/>}/>
         <Route path="/products" element={<Products/>}/>
       </Route>
       <Route path="/login" element={<Authentication />}/>
     </Routes>
  )
}
```

In your `Layout`

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```

I think it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The routes/routed components are not configured correctly to allow for rendering descendent or nested routes.

### Descendent Routes

In order for the `MainContent` component, via `Global` rendered on the `"/"` path, to render descendent routes its parent route necessarily needs to append the path wildcard matcher `"*"` to its path so descendent routes can also be matched. `path="/*"` instead of just `path="/"`.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<Global />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Authentication />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

### Nested Routes

You could also convert `MainContent` into a layout route where it renders an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their content into.

MainContent

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const MainContent = () => {
  return (
    <div className='content-body'>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

```
...
import Sales from '../../pages/Sales'
import Products from '../../pages/Products'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Global />}>
        <Route path="sales" element={<Sales />} />
        <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Authentication />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

See [layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for more details.